# Get textbox value in a GridView templatefield using Jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am using a text box inside a GridView as ItemTemplate field. I have a requirement to get the value of the text box usingJquery. How can I do that? How can I get the textbox object under a GridView in Jquery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By using a jQuery selector and the `.val()` method. I think you'll need to provide an example of your HTML to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i find out myself.... Ans of this question...

Use a class for that text box and use following code

```
$('.qty').live('change', function() {
///code here
           });
```

where `qty` is the class name of the text box